# WCF Sign only the body

Tags: .net, wcf, sign

I'm trying to connect to a Java service via WCF. The service expects that the body, and only the body of the SOAP message were signed.

I'm making a custom binding with MutualCertificate security, but it seems that this signs not only the body but also the header (or a part of it).

Is that true?

And if it is, How can I make to only sign the body?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you can use:

`[MessageBodyMember(ProtectionLevel=ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign)]`

or

```
[MessageBodyMember(ProtectionLevel=ProtectionLevel.Sign)]
```

to highlight what you want signed/encrypted?

Comment: i want that only the body signed, not any part of the header

Comment: exactly - so each body member add that tag to.

Comment: uh.. not so simple because even those parts that don't have this decorator will be `SignAndEncrypt`'d. Because that is the default. To make this work he would have to first set `ProtectionLevel=ProtectionLevel.None` at the top of the contract interface level and then override it to `Sign` at each individual message body as per your decorator example. And he is using transport security so there is no need for encryption, just signing.